# Optimistic locking with hibernate and trigger - "Strange" behaviour

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I want to use the optimistic locking feature present in hibernate. To do this I configured the mapping for my table as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="org.example.dao.entity">
    <class name="org.example.dao.entity.EmployeeEntity" table="employee" dynamic-update="false">
        <id name="id" column="employee_id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <version name="version" column="version" type="java.lang.Integer" generated="always"/>
        <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <set name="projects" table="employee_to_project" inverse="true">
            <key column="employee_id"/>
            <many-to-many column="project_id" class="ProjectEntity"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I used generated="always" and created the following trigger in db:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tab_employee_update_version()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$
BEGIN
  NEW.version = coalesce(OLD.version,0) + 1;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$
/
```

Then I run the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");

        final EmployeeService employeeService = ctx.getBean("employeeService", EmployeeService.class);

        // SELECT
        Employee employee = employeeService.getById(1L);

        // UPDATE
        employeeService.update(employee);    
    }
```

and get the HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException despite the fact that employee record was not changed by another transaction meantime:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [org.example.dao.entity.EmployeeEntity] with identifier [1]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [org.example.dao.entity.EmployeeEntity#1]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:202)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:592)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.example.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [org.example.dao.entity.EmployeeEntity#1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2541)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3285)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)
    ... 14 more
```

Transaction boundaries are on service level (the EmployeeService class is marked with the @Transactional annotation).

I debugged the code and found out, that hibernate automatically increases the version during the update:

```
Hibernate: select employeeen0_.employee_id as employee1_1_0_, employeeen0_.version as version2_1_0_, employeeen0_.age as age3_1_0_, employeeen0_.first_name as first_na4_1_0_, employeeen0_.last_name as last_nam5_1_0_ from employee employeeen0_ where employeeen0_.employee_id=?
10:36:46,258 TRACE main sql.BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
10:36:46,270 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([version2_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [57]
10:36:46,270 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([age3_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [0]
10:36:46,271 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([first_na4_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bogumil]
10:36:46,271 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([last_nam5_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bednarek]
10:36:46,280 TRACE main type.CollectionType:783 - Created collection wrapper: [org.example.dao.entity.EmployeeEntity.projects#1]

Hibernate: select projects0_.employee_id as employee1_1_0_, projects0_.project_id as project_2_2_0_, projectent1_.project_id as project_1_3_1_, projectent1_.name as name2_3_1_ from employee_to_project projects0_ inner join project projectent1_ on projects0_.project_id=projectent1_.project_id where projects0_.employee_id=?
10:36:46,394 TRACE main sql.BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
10:36:46,397 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([project_1_3_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
10:36:46,397 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([name2_3_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Project1]
10:36:46,398 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([employee1_1_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
10:36:46,398 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([project_2_2_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
10:36:46,399 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([project_1_3_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [2]
10:36:46,399 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([name2_3_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Project2]
10:36:46,400 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([employee1_1_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
10:36:46,400 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([project_2_2_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [2]

Hibernate: update employee set age=?, first_name=?, last_name=? where employee_id=? and version=?
10:36:46,426 TRACE main sql.BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
10:36:46,426 TRACE main sql.BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Bogumil]
10:36:46,427 TRACE main sql.BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Bednarek]
10:36:46,427 TRACE main sql.BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [1]
10:36:46,427 TRACE main sql.BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [58]
```

Additionally, I found out that if I select and update a record in the same transaction, hibernate does not increase the version and everything works fine.

And one more observation. After removing the 'set' element from the mapping file, everything works fine:

```
<set name="projects" table="employee_to_project" inverse="true">
    <key column="employee_id"/>
    <many-to-many column="project_id" class="ProjectEntity"/>
</set>
```

**Can somebody explain me, why hibernate increases the version and therefore I get the exception?**

More details about my application:

- springframework version: 4.2.0.RELEASE
- hibernate version: 4.3.11.Final
- postgreSQL version: 9.3

Comment: Post the stacktrace. Generally there is at least a reason explained in the stacktrace exlaining why the HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException has been thrown.

Comment: I added the stacktrace. The reason the exception is thrown is because hibernate increments the version before the update. Therefore, the hibernate tries to update a record which does not exist in db.

Comment: I don't really understand why you create that version updating trigger. You say that Hibernate does it, but there is no proof of that in the logs you post.

Comment: The value of version in db is **57**: `10:36:46,270 TRACE main sql.BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([version2_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [57])`. Then, when hibernate makes an update, it increases the version to  **58**: `10:36:46,427 TRACE main sql.BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [58]`

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace the problem is "*Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)*".

If the problem is related to the transaction there are three possibilities:

- Your code try to do an update on the same row in two different points (but you already checked it and this is not the problem)
- You had an exception on the same row in a previous test and the code didn't handled correctly the rollback so the old transaction is not closed
- There is a transaction not closed on the row you are trying to update. Perhaps that you updated that row with a client (toad, sqlserver, mysql workbench, squirrel... ) and never committed the data.

Comment: I wrote a simple java spring application to execute the test. I run this aplication to execute the test, then the application closes. There are no other clients working in the background (no toad, workbench, etc.). Each time I run the test, the exception is thrown.

Comment: Try to check directly on the database if the record is locked while your application is NOT running.

Comment: It is not. I run SELECT... FOR UPDATE and it succeeded.